# Prevent form submit on tab switch with richfaces tabPanel

Tags: jsf, tabs, richfaces, submit

Got a tab panel something like:

```
<rich:tabPanel  >
    <rich:tab header="Description"  >
        <ui:include src="./tests/description.xhtml"/>                   
    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab header="Something else">
        something else
    </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

With a few fields in description.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:advanced="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/advanced">    

    <h:panelGroup id="description">        
        // ...
        <h:outputLabel  value="Name"/> 
        <h:inputText    id="name"
                        value="#{testTree.selected.name.text}" 
                        rendered="#{description.editing}"/>      
        // ...
        <advanced:button text="Reset" //Just a little upgraded a4j:commandButton
                         icon="images/clear.png"
                         action="#{description.resetEditing()}"
                         execute="@this"                                
                         render="description"
                         rendered="#{description.editing}"/>               
        <advanced:button text="Save"
                         icon="images/save2.png"
                         action="#{description.commitEditing()}"
                         execute="description" // #name and a few more fields                  
                         render="description"
                         rendered="#{description.editing}"/> 
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

Switching to the second tab I got my "description" form submitted and this is not good. I want to reset all fields instead.

How can I achieve this with RichFaces 4?

Answer (score 1):

By default when switching between tabs the parent tabPanel is submitted. You can change this behaviour using the switchType attribute of the tabPanel to either ajax or client. I can think of two ways to prevent your form from being submitted on changing from one tab to another:

1. Change the switchType attribute to client
2. Include a form for each tab

I can't see where your form is defined but I am guessing the whole rich:tabPanel is inside the form. I see there is no form defined in your description.xhtml page. You can try removing the form that you have and then add a form for each tab, i.e. in description.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:advanced="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/advanced">    

<a4j:form>
<h:panelGroup id="description">        
    // ...
    <h:outputLabel  value="Name"/> 
    <h:inputText    id="name"
                    value="#{testTree.selected.name.text}" 
                    rendered="#{description.editing}"/>      
    // ...
    <advanced:button text="Reset" //Just a little upgraded a4j:commandButton
                     icon="images/clear.png"
                     action="#{description.resetEditing()}"
                     execute="@this"                                
                     render="description"
                     rendered="#{description.editing}"/>               
    <advanced:button text="Save"
                     icon="images/save2.png"
                     action="#{description.commitEditing()}"
                     execute="description" // #name and a few more fields                  
                     render="description"
                     rendered="#{description.editing}"/> 
</h:panelGroup>
</a4j:form>
</ui:composition>
```

I would also set the switchType attribute of the tabPanel to ajax so that only the content of tabPanel is refreshed.

Comment: i thought i HAVE TO have a form around tabPanel, if not it wont work... indeed: class org.richfaces.component.UITabPanel (id="j_id2114509110_7e08d978") did not find parent form.

Answer (score 0):

1) Change the switchType attribute to client
2) Include a form for each tab

I have spent 6 hours googling , finally ended here searching for another,
Changing this attribute value saved my day.